# Error when trying to import SQLite into node

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, npm, node-sqlite3

i have been having trouble trying to import SQLite into node. This is my import statement:

```
import * as sqlite from './sqlite';
```

However I am given this error

```
node:internal/process/esm_loader:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'D:\WebPro\WebProg\cwCode\sqlite' imported from D:\WebPro\WebProg\cwCode\dbInteract.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:329:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:323:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:758:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:869:11)
    at Loader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:86:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:230:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:57:40)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:56:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

As shown below, I have both SQLite and SQLite3 in my dependencies and when i look in the node modules folder both packages are there.

```
{
  "name": "webpro-coursework",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "web programming coursework 2021",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node svr.js"
  },
  "author": "up939702",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "md5-file": "^5.0.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.2",
    "sqlite": "^4.0.21",
    "sqlite3": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7"
  }
}
```

```
    },
    "node_modules/sqlite": {
      "version": "4.0.21",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlite/-/sqlite-4.0.21.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-HIqObuvz+Vx8BXWzIhR12fJMjiE37Mdfupg2Ok0f8MChSqALXj7FgpZauj1pJoSY6qsDYmp/+/ZgSn3l8yutoA=="
    },
    "node_modules/sqlite3": {
      "version": "5.0.2",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/sqlite3/-/sqlite3-5.0.2.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-1SdTNo+BVU211Xj1csWa8lV6KM0CtucDwRyA0VHl91wEH1Mgh7RxUpI4rVvG7OhHrzCSGaVyW5g8vKvlrk9DJA==",
      "hasInstallScript": true,
      "dependencies": {
        "node-addon-api": "^3.0.0",
        "node-pre-gyp": "^0.11.0"
      },
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated <3

Comment: You seem to be showing the content of your `package.json` file. That shows only the dependencies. If those dependencies are really installed, you need to check the `package-lock.json` file.

Comment: @yunzen i have just added the relevant lines of the package-lock.

Comment: With "./sqlite", you're specifying an (incorrect) path to the module - you see in your error message that the path that is being resolved is "'D:\WebPro\WebProg\cwCode\sqlite". For external dependencies, just specify the module name rather than a path - ie in this case "sqlite".

Comment: @IAmDranged I have tried this and it still throws errors

Comment: What is the actual error message then?

Comment: npm install sqlite

Comment: Give that another go and see if it was just a bug. Cannot find module should always be the tall tail that you need to install it. If you're getting that, see what install suggests. Worse case clear project packages and restart init it all. Also noticing sqlite and sqlite3; You should probably run a delete on the two and reinstall.

Comment: Last but not least, are you sure you want to use SQLLite? It's really nothing of that production grade quality, mostly MySQL/Redis and those are widely known/supported less hassle.

Answer (score 1):

You should try:

```
import * as sqlite from 'sqlite';
```